# Playwright - Cucumber - ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: javascript, playwright, cucumberjs

Hi people: Working on Playwright with Cucumber and Javascript I'm facing the next issue trying to run the framework.

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
```

This is my **cucumber.mjs** file:

```
const common = `
    features/**/*.feature
  --require setup/assertions.cjs
  --require setup/hooks.cjs
  --require step-definitions/**/*.steps.js
  --publish-quiet
  `;

module.exports = {
    default: `${common} features/!**/!*.feature`
};
```

The error message says that the expression "exports" causes this issue.

Please don't tell me that remove the "type": "module", from package.json.

By the way: I tried to run the framework with the next command:

```
npm run test -- --tags "@Begin"
```

@Begin is a tag included in the Cucumber file.

Please, if you can help me with this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Shouldn't this be a cjs file? mjs is for ESM, which is `import asdf from "asdf";` and `export default asdf;`. cjs is `require("adsf");` and `module.exports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using CommonJS modules, so you should use the `.cjs` file extension, not the `.mjs` file extension.

.cjs: CommonJS, importing using `require("adsf")` and exporting using `module.exports`

.mjs: ES Modules, importing using `import asdf from "asdf"` and exporting using `export default asdf`

Comment: Yes: I changed the extension for cjs in that file and other 2 and the message is no longer. Thanks a lot kmeh!!!

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I run the script and the browser opens, but it closes... Launch Browser
Create a new Context and Page
.UUU.Close Context and Page
.close Browser
And it says that the step definitions are undefined, but I have them defined.

Comment: That's not a problem with the module types, that's just some other JavaScript error. I can't tell you what the problem is without you posting the full code (preferably as a new question so that other people can also assist you).

Comment: THanks again kmeh: I will open a new post.